# Scrape entire webpage + css + javascript

Tags: javascript, css, go, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a webpage version control backup / log. Where if the webpage (including JS and CSS) gets altered it saves a static copy on the drive.

How do I `get` the CSS and javascript of a webpage? Getting the HTML is easy by simply connecting to the webpage and read the contents and return it. But how do I get the CSS & Javascript of this page too?

The system doesnt have direct access to the webserver(s) so I have to do everything over the `network` remotely.

My idea is I search the HTML I scraped for `.css` and '.js' and take everything until the first quote `"` and directly access the CSS / javascript file as webpage. But I think this might not be very reliable?

Not sure why this is marked as too broad. I'm asking how to get the CSS and javascript of a webpage. I reformed my question, hopefully its better now.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of searching for `.js` and `.css` , I'd look for `<script>` and `<link>` tags instead and use their `src` and `href` properties respectively to perform another network request and retrieve those files for comparison.

This will be more reliable because you won't have to worry about the page's content containing `js` or `css`, and you could also use an XML parser to ensure things like single-quotes vs. double aren't an issue.